# Como recorrer un array Json con Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonarray, chart.js

Hola gente me estoy iniciando en el mundo de jquery con respuestas asincronas, tengo un array que lo traigo desde mi controller, mi array es tipo:

```js
{[
{"Name":"Route 1","Quantity":21576.000000},
{"Name":"Route 3","Quantity":14129.000000},
{"Name":"Route 4","Quantity":13765.000000},
{"Name":"Route 5","Quantity":15667.000000}
]}
```

bien necesito recorrer ese array para asignarselo a otros arreglos porque estoy trabajando con chartJS, tenia algo como esto, pero no me devuelve nada

```js
$("#gh1").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/MiJsonResult", function (data) {
        var label = [];
        var point = [];
        $.each(e => {
            label.push(e.Name)
            point.push(e.Quantity)
        });     
    });
});
```

Osea quiero extraer todo lo que dice "Name" para que sean mis etiquetas y "Quantity" serian mis puntos a graficar. Espero puedan ayudarme ya no se que hacer.

Comment: No es `data.Name` en lugar de `e.Name`?

Comment: me devuelve asi si hago eso: 
Array []​
length: 0
​

Comment: intenta enviar solo un texto, y luego verificas que sí te esté recibiendo el texto.. porque a lo que dices que te retorna, dice que el arreglo está vacío

Answer (score 0):

el each debería recorrer tu respuesta "data"

```
$("#gh1").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/MiJsonResult", function (data) {
        var label = [];
        var point = [];
        $.each(data, function(i,d){
            label.push(d.Name)
            point.push(d.Quantity)
        });     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que parsear primero los datos obtenido a formato Json, a que normalmente, lo que se recibe, es en formato string, por lo que tendrás que parsearlo antes de recorrer los datos.

```
$("#gh1").click(function () {
$.getJSON("/Home/MiJsonResult", function (data) {
    var label = [];
    var point = [];
    var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(parseData , function(i,d){
        label.push(d.Name)
        point.push(d.Quantity)
    });     
});
});
```